# Swipe a division and make it follow the swipe direction

Tags: javascript, html, touch, zepto

I am using Zepto (with the Touch Module)
I have a div with a 'swipe' listener on it.
I want the div to follow the finger of the user when swiping it, just as you swipe away your notifications on your Android or iPhone.
Is there a way of getting the swipe/finger position on the swipe event? so I can put the div to `position: relative` with a `left: [finger left position]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for it, you have to bind it to the touchmove event, not the swipe one:

```
$(".element").on('touchmove', function( e ){
    var x = e.touches[0].pageX;
    $(this).css('left', x);
});
```

And of course add an `ontouchend` event in order to replace the element where it was in the beginning (in case the user released the swiped element)

It's also even better to use `-webkit-translate: (70px 0px)` for faster performance (replace 70px with x)